# Surface Tension and Potential Energy in a Lagrangian

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, potential-energy, surface-tension

It seems natural to define the potential energy due to surface tension to be 
$U = \int \sigma dA$. But then I have the following problem.  I wanted to investigate surface tension in a simple dynamical scenario I made up.

Consider an empty thin sphere of radius $r$, surface tension $\sigma$ and internal pressure $p$. Combining the potential energies from surface tension and pressure, I get a potential:
$$
V(r) = 4 \pi \sigma r^2 - \frac{4}{3} \pi p r^3
$$
I made a lagrangian out of this potential by adding a kinetic term for the radius:
$$
L = \frac{1}{2}m \dot{r}^2 - V(r)
$$
I am assuming the variations in r are small enough that the pressure doesn't change appreciably. My expectation was that this would show the radius oscillating around the equilibrium point $r = \frac{2\sigma}{p}$. But if you actually plot the potential, you see that equilibrium point corresponds to a local maximum, not a local minimum, and so the equilibrium point is unstable.

To fix this you could define the potential energy to be the negative of my original guess, and then the potential shows oscillations about the equilibrium. However, the new potential energy due to surface tension is $-4\pi \sigma r^2$ and it looks like the potential energy of the surface itself is unbounded below, that the energy can decrease by increasing surface area, which doesn't make sense.

So, I'm very confused about the appropriate signs here. How should the potential in this case be defined?  I also could be completely wrong about setting up the scenario, so more general, how would one add the potential due to surface tension to a physical model?

Comment: wouldn't the pressure be negative, no?

Comment: You need to include changes in pressure, if the bubble is compressible (ie can change volume but not mass) then it is the balance between pressure and tension that will define its volume and oscillation.